# Error occuring in docker pull

Tags: docker

I tried to pull an image from docker hub using

**docker pull alpine**

but it shows

**Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: dial tcp: lookup registry-1.docker.io on 10.0.2.3:53: read udp 10.0.2.15:57942->10.0.2.3:53: i/o timeout**

What is the problem and what does this mean?

Comment: Is the 
IP address of your name server 1
0.2.3? This name server didn't respond the DNS query of docker .

Comment: The problem seems to be resolved.I tried it today and now it's pulling alpine image successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Default docker pull registry url issue

The default registry for docker images is just hub.docker.com 3, so docker pull redis will automatically pull it from there.

Try something like this.

```
docker pull registry.hub.docker.com/library/alpine
```

Comment: The problem seems to be resolved.I tried it today and now it's pulling alpine image successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This problem will solve by adding nameservers

So, You can edit file `/etc/resolv.conf` and just add the following under existing nameservers

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Now try to pull image you want:

```
docker pull alpine
```